# Loop is not iterating on all JSON dataset

Tags: javascript, json

Over here in the JSON dataset, the loop is iterating just on the first pokemon i.e true for Bulbasaur only. If you type any other pokemon's name it's showing "Not found". If you type in "Ivysaur" or any other pokemon name like "Venusaur" it's not showing.  Check out my code below.

```
    let findpokemongame = {https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Biuni/PokemonGO-Pokedex/master/pokedex.json} //click the link to find the JSON dataset

        var findname = window.prompt("Enter Pokemon Name")
let checkname = function(findname, findpokemongame) {
  for (let thispokemon in findpokemongame.pokemon) {
    if (findpokemongame.pokemon[thispokemon].name == findname) {
      let pokemondetails = findpokemongame.pokemon[thispokemon];
      console.log(pokemondetails);
      for (info in pokemondetails) {
        if (typeof pokemondetails[info][0] === 'object') {
          pokemondetails[info] = pokemondetails[info].map(o => o.name)
        }

        alert(info + " : " + pokemondetails[info] + "\n")

      }
    }
    else{
      alert('Not found');
      break;
    }
  }
}

checkname(findname, findpokemongame)
```

Comment: Can you show the JSON Data, please?

Comment: added it. check out the link

Answer (score 2):

Your code is very nested and complex. Personally, I'd use [array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the pokemon and simplify the code. Once you've found it, then you can do other (separate) operations on it and hopefully any errors will become obvious:

```
const foundPokemon = findpokemongame.pokemon.find(pokemon => pokemon.name === findname);

// check foundPokemon
if (foundPokemon) {
  // once found extract any details..
} else {
  // pokemon name not found
}
```

How are you handling name cases? Its probably better to convert both user input and json data pokemon names to lower case ([string.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)) before comparing them.